# How to tell when user selects text in NSTextView

Tags: macos, nstextview

I have an `NSTextView` and want to be able to tell when the user highlights (selects) a portion of the text, so that I can make changes to it. The `NSTextViewDelegate` protocol doesn't seem to have a method for this. Is there a way to capture this event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure `- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(NSNotification *)aNotification` doesn't do the trick? It's part of `NSTextViewDelegate` ([reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/NSTextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSTextViewDelegate/textViewDidChangeSelection%3a)). If it doesn't work the way you want, what specifically are you looking for?

Comment: Of note, this delegate method is called even if the selection is done programmatically: after a `selectAll()` call, for example, or if the text view's `string` if changed.